# Xamarin.Forms - FormsAppCompatActivity or ForsmApplicationActivity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I am new to Xamarin.Forms and i cannot find information about the different between global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity and global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity in Android project. Can someone explain differents between those two classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you most likely should be using `FormsAppCompatActivity`. This is an `Activity` suitable to using Material Design on Android. It wasn’t until the introduction of the updated AppCompat v7 Support Library that devices running earlier versions of Android could use Material Design. Switching to `FormsAppCompatActivity` enables you to use these features.

It has been around since Xamarin.Forms 1.5 and seeing as how we're at 2.3.4 currently you are most likely better off using `FormsAppCompatActivity` going into the future.