# FormsAppCompatActivity vs MainActivity

Tags: android, xamarin

I am have interview tomorrow i am need to know the difference between `FormsAppCompatActivity vs MainActivity`.. I have searched ithe internet but from what i found it seems that `MainActivity` is the base class and `FormsAppCompatActivity` derives from `MainActivity` and the main difference seems to be in the tool bar ?

```
seen this
```

[Activity, AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity, and ActionBarActivity: When to Use Which?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297246/activity-appcompatactivity-fragmentactivity-and-actionbaractivity-when-to-us)
[Xamarin.Forms - FormsAppCompatActivity or ForsmApplicationActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45051398/xamarin-forms-formsappcompatactivity-or-forsmapplicationactivity)
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/115952/xamarin-forms-formsapplicationactivity-or-formsappcompatactivity
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/material-theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainActivity` is the main class for a Xamarin Android project

`FormsAppCompatActivity` is the main class for a Xamarin Forms Android project